# why only main activity ondestroy is called in android when we close the app

Tags: android

My android application consists of many activities. The very first activity that is called when app is opened is Login activity. After that the user navigates to many activities. But when the user close the app, only the onDestroy method of Login activity is called. Why does the android system calls only the first activity onDestroy, not others? 
If the system is designed in such a way to call only first activity onDestroy, then  can we expect that it will be called for sure everytime we close the app?

Comment: How do you know that onpy the onDestroy of the login activity is called? Have you checked the log?

Comment: yes, I have checked the log. I am seeing this behavior from many days.

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Develper Doc for `onDestory()`

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's
>   hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so
>   it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question.

In short, other activities are also closed altogether by the system, but their `onDestroy()` methods are not called. They just get killed. Only the main activity's `onDestroy()` gets called.

read this, valeonom's comments:

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2s2hqh/whats_the_point_of_ondestroy_if_we_can_never/

and this:

[Why only the first activity's `onDestroy` is called, not other activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065114/why-only-the-first-activitys-ondestroy-is-called-not-other-activities/66065224#66065224)