# Why only the first activity's `onDestroy` is called, not other activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

(I searched quite a bit, but there seems no exact answer for this.)

Let's say there's an app. We can push a button to start another activity.

Like this: `Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Activity3`

If we use the 'back' button, it calls the `finish()`, so each activity's `onDestroy()` gets called.

***But,*** if we close the app(by pushing the 'overview' button and then swipe the app out),

only the `Activity1`'s `onDestroy()` gets called.

1. Why the `onDestroy()` of other activities are not called?
2. Does it mean that other activities are *alive* until the system kills them?
   (If the system has enough resources, they are not destroyed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally when you force close the `App` from `overview`, it kills the entire app process and all the `activities` are destroyed, and your activity stack root's(which is `ActivityA`) `onDestroy` method is called and for other `activities` the `method` won't be triggered but the `stack` itself gets destroyed along with the process. Nothing will be alive once the process is destroyed.